# Install maven in eclipse 3.8 in Ubuntu

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, ubuntu

I have installed "default" eclipse 3.8 in Ubuntu. I would like to install Maven support on it. I do

1) In eclipse, go to "Help->Install New Software"

2) press "Add" in the upper right button in the opened window

3) set the name textbox to be "Maven2Eclipse"

4) set the value textbox to be http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases

5) after press OK I got following error:

```
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Maven Integration for Eclipse JDT UI 1.5.1.20150109-1820 (org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.ui 1.5.1.20150109-1820)



    Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
      Software being installed: m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse (includes Incubating components) 1.5.1.20150109-1820 (org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 1.5.1.20150109-1820)
      Missing requirement: Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.5.0.20140606-0033 (org.eclipse.m2e.core 1.5.0.20140606-0033) requires 'bundle org.slf4j.api 1.6.2' but it could not be found
      Missing requirement: Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.5.1.20150109-1820 (org.eclipse.m2e.core 1.5.1.20150109-1820) requires 'bundle org.slf4j.api 1.6.2' but it could not be found
      Missing requirement: Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.5.2.20150413-2215 (org.eclipse.m2e.core 1.5.2.20150413-2215) requires 'bundle org.slf4j.api 1.6.2' but it could not be found
      Cannot satisfy dependency:
        From: m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse (includes Incubating components) 1.5.1.20150109-1820 (org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 1.5.1.20150109-1820)
        To: org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.ui [1.5.1.20150109-1820]
      Cannot satisfy dependency:
        From: Maven Integration for Eclipse JDT UI 1.5.1.20150109-1820 (org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.ui 1.5.1.20150109-1820)
        To: bundle org.eclipse.m2e.core [1.5.0,1.6.0)
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like it might be a version issue.

I've never had any problem installing Maven (or SVN, or any related plugins) ... but I don't happen to have a copy of Juno handy to double-check for you.

SUGGESTION:

1. Make sure you're pointing to the Eclipse 3.8 (and *only* 3.8) repositories
2. Try installing m2e with that repo

http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.8.2-201301310800/

http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno/

ADDENDUM:

Here's what I did on Luna, on CentOS Linux:

1. Eclipse > Help > Install Software (*not* "Marketplace*)
2. Work With > http://downloads.eclipse.org/releases/luna
3. filter text > m2e, [ENTER]
4. m2e Maven Integration = Y <= the package you want

   m2e sl4j = Y <= the dependency in your error

[image: Install m2e integration and sl4j packages]

5. [Finish] => everything installed OK

Comment: got the same issue with http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno/ and it not connects to first one

Comment: http://downloads.eclipse.org/releases/luna or http://downloads.eclipse.org/releases/juno (I suppose this is my version) tells "No software found..."

Comment: Q: Is it possible to simply install a newer, current version of Eclipse?  Different Eclipse versions can co-exist side-by-side - you just point to a different workspace.  Q: Can you try explicitly installing m2e/slf4j from the same place you installed m2e?

Answer (score 1):

What I did was first of all, running eclipse with root privileges in order to update the environment: Eclipse > Help > Check for Updates.
Then I could install maven as said above, Eclipse > Help > Install Software, etc, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Same error i was getting today .

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse (includes Incubating components) 1.8.1.20170728-1531 (org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 1.8.1.20170728-1531)
  Missing requirement: Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.8.1.20170728-1531 (org.eclipse.m2e.core 1.8.1.20170728-1531) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.osgi 3.10.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.8.1.20170728-1531 (org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui 1.8.1.20170728-1531)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.m2e.core [1.8.1,1.9.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse (includes Incubating components) 1.8.1.20170728-1531 (org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 1.8.1.20170728-1531)
    To: org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui [1.8.1.20170728-1531]
```

After spending a lot hours i found that http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases will not work . 
Now steps to solve error is ,
Open Eclipse -> Help -> Install New Software -> Add http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.3
. It should definatly solve your issue